# What is the point of using NSTableCellView when creating view-based tables?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

When you create a view-based table view in Xcode's interface builder, it automatically adds an `NSTableCellView` control, inside of which is an `NSTextField` control. You better add constraints to your text field control, otherwise it won't resize properly when you resize a column.

But it turns out that `NSTableCellView` controls are unnecessary. You can just use a `NSTextField` control, or any view that you like, in its place. And you won't need to add constraints; the control will resize automatically. So what it is the point of using an `NSTableCellView` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for when your cells are compound views. For example, when you have an image and a text label, or more complex hierarchies.

When your cell view is a multi-view hierarchy, you need a container view. That doesn't have to be `NSTableCellView`, but `NSTableCellView` provides some nice conveniences, like an `objectValue` property and the outlets to the `imageView` and `textField`.

Comment: `objectValue` may be the most useful baked-in property, as both NSTableViewDataSource and tableview content bindings set it for the cell views.  And, of course, the delegate API requires NSTableCellView subclasses in the first place...

Comment: Where does the delegate API require `NSTableCellView`? I don't think it does.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, it's not.  It is interesting to read the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableCellView_Class/) which makes it seem like cell reuse might not happen without the NSTableCellView subclass?  But otherwise says, sure, use something else and implement an objectValue property if you want it.